# How can I add a full stop at the end of a word without there being a space in between the word and the full stop?

Tags: python, printing, spaces

I want to execute a code wherein I take 5 seperate words as input and then output 5 words with space in between them and add a full stop such that there is no space between the last word and the full stop.

If I use the code:

```
w1 = input()
w2 = input()
w3 = input()
w4 = input()
w5 = input()
print(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,".")
```

If the input is:

```
one
and
two
are
numbers
```

Then the output is:

```
one and two are numbers .
```

And not:

```
one and two are numbers.
```

I am new to python
Please tell me how I can fix this error :(

Comment: Practise using arrays and for loops when reading input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5 + ".")` instead of `print(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,".")`. When you place commas in between arguments to `print`, it automatically places spaces between them.